# Aframe : Animation not working on the collada model from mixamo

Tags: aframe, gltf

The animation for the model is not playing. Here are the steps I followed:

1. I first downloaded a 'Walking.dae' collada file from mixamo
2. I then converted the collada format to .gltf 2.0 using the KhronosGroup/glTF online converter.
3. Then I used the animation-mixer by don mccurdy in the code.

Problems:

1. The first problem I immediately observe from the browser console is the following: 'components:gltf-model:warn Failed to load glTF model'. So is there a conversion problem from the KhronosGroup/glTF online converter?
2. I tried my best but could not find the url that we use in the `<script scr="path">`. Can this "path" to the animation-mixer.js file by don mccurdy be provided to me?
3. Lastly is this the code using which my model can show the animation or is there anymore to this?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <!--script url for animation mixer from don mccurdy-->  
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
    <a-sky color="#6EBAA7"></a-sky>
        <a-entity gltf-model="Walking.gltf" animation-mixer="clip: Idle"></a-entity>
        <a-entity position="0 1 2"><a-camera></a-camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

The model and the animation have been downloaded from Mixamo. I have also placed the downloaded .dae files in the same folder as that of the html I am running. Here is the structure:

[The directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqyru.png)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `model-animation` a component you wrote? I don’t see it imported. Unrelated but should be using A-Frame 0.8.2

Comment: @DiegoMarcos to be honest, I just found this code somewhere and I was just trying to run it(dumb of me). I don't even know if it's workable or not. I searched aframe docs but I could not get anything about model animations. Although I looked into gltf animation model github thingy, I found this code on github community where you could animate colada objects directly without converting them to gltf. All I really need a reference of how you could animate a model. Also the aframe 8.2 point is duly noted! Thanks!

Comment: @DiegoMarcos...any leads on this?

Comment: Probably best is to reach out the author of the model-animation component. Without more code and context is going to be hard for people to help you.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos Fair and true enough. Will look into the same. Thank you.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos...I updated the question sir. And also the code along with some gltf models.

Comment: This is the only workflow I've used successfully with Mixamo: https://www.donmccurdy.com/2017/11/06/creating-animated-gltf-characters-with-mixamo-and-blender/

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I actually followed the same tutorial and I finally got it working but instead of using gltf models, I directly used the .fbx model along with the inflate.min.js file for using the FBXLoader. I know that gltf models are faster to load or better to use maybe, but I just could not find the libraries and stuff. Other than your documentation part, there is absolutely nothing on this out there :( . Hope that AFrame documentation gets a lot better in the future for using 3rd party stuff.

Comment: Glad you were able to get something working! If there's a particular area missing from the docs (related to A-Frame, A-Frame Extras, or Blender?), please feel free to file an issue too.